# AVL tree string insertion Error (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x28))

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I have a somewhat working AVL tree, my program contains a 'TreeType.h' file and a 'main.cpp' (I will attach code below). In my main.cpp I am inserting string's into the AVL tree in the following order:

```
tree.InsertItem("dean");
tree.InsertItem("joe");
tree.InsertItem("jason");
```

which works fine, however if I stop the program and switch the data around so the strings being inserted are as follows:

```
tree.InsertItem("joe");
tree.InsertItem("dean");
tree.InsertItem("jason");
```

and then I run the program again, I then get the following runtime error '(Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x28))' I have no idea what this means or how to correct it as I am relatively new to programming.

TreeType.h

```
#ifndef AvlClass_h
#define AvlClass_h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef enum {LH,EH,RH} Balfactor;

template <class ItemType>
struct TreeNode
{
    ItemType info;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    Balfactor bf;
};

template <class ItemType>
class TreeType
{
public:
    void InsertItem(ItemType item);
    void Print();
private:
    TreeNode <ItemType> * root;
};

template <class ItemType>
void TreeType<ItemType> ::Print()
{
    PrintPostorder(root);
}

template <class ItemType>
void PrintPostorder(TreeNode<ItemType>*&  tree)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
        return;
    // first recur on left subtree
    PrintPostorder(tree->left);

    // then recur on right subtree
    PrintPostorder(tree->right);

    // now deal with the node
    cout << tree->info << "\n";
}


template <class ItemType>
void TreeType<ItemType> :: InsertItem(ItemType item)
// Calls recursive function Insert to insert item into tree.
{
    bool taller=false;
    Insert (root, item, taller);
}

template <class ItemType>
void Insert (TreeNode<ItemType>*& tree, ItemType item, bool & taller)
// Inserts item into tree.
// Post:item is in tree; search property is maintained.
{
    if (tree == NULL)
    {    // Insertion place found.
        tree = new TreeNode<ItemType>;
        tree->left = NULL;
        tree->right = NULL;
        tree->info = item;
        tree->bf = EH;
        taller = true;
    }
    else if ( item == tree->info)
        cerr << "Duplicate key is not allowed in AVL tree." << endl;
    else if (item < tree->info)
    {
        Insert (tree->left, item, taller);
        // Insert into left subtree
        if (taller)
            switch (tree->bf)
        {
            case LH: LeftBalance(tree,taller);
                break;
            case EH: tree->bf = LH;
                break;
            case RH: tree->bf = EH;
                taller = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Insert (tree->right, item, taller);
        // Insert into right subtree
        if (taller)
            switch (tree->bf)
        {
            case RH: RightBalance (tree,taller);
                break;
            case EH: tree->bf = RH;
                break;
            case LH: tree->bf = EH;
                taller = false;
                break;
        }

    }
}

template <class ItemType>
void RotateLeft (TreeNode<ItemType> * & tree)
{
    TreeNode<ItemType> * rs;
    if (tree == NULL)
        cerr << "It is impossible to rotate an empty tree in RotateLeft" << endl;
    else if (tree->right == NULL)
        cerr << "It is impossible to make an empty subtree the root in RotateLeft" << endl;
    else
    {
        rs = tree->right;
        tree->right = rs->left;
        rs->left = tree;
        tree = rs;

    }
}

template <class ItemType>
void RotateRight (TreeNode<ItemType> * & tree)
{
    TreeNode<ItemType> * ls;
    if (tree == NULL)
        cerr << "It is impossible to rotate an empty tree in RotateRight" << endl;
    else if (tree->left == NULL)
        cerr << "It is impossible to make an empty subtree the root in RotateRight" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        ls = tree->left;
        tree->left = ls->right;
        ls->right = tree;
        tree = ls;

    }

}

template <class ItemType>
void RightBalance (TreeNode<ItemType> *& tree, bool & taller)
{
    TreeNode<ItemType> * rs = tree->right;
    TreeNode<ItemType> * ls;
    switch (rs->bf)
    {
        case RH:
            tree->bf = rs->bf = EH;
            RotateLeft(tree);
            taller = false;
            break;
        case EH:
            std::cerr << "Tree already balanced " << std::endl;
            break;
        case LH:
            ls = rs->left;
            switch (ls->bf)
        {
            case RH:
                tree->bf = LH;
                rs->bf = EH;
                break;
            case EH:
                tree->bf = rs->bf = EH;
                break;
            case LH:
                tree->bf = EH;
                rs->bf = RH;
                break;
        }
            ls->bf = EH;
            RotateRight(tree->right);
            RotateLeft(tree);
            taller = false;
    }
}


template <class ItemType>
void LeftBalance (TreeNode<ItemType> *& tree, bool & taller)
 {
     TreeNode<ItemType> * ls = tree->left;
     TreeNode<ItemType> * rs;
     switch (ls->bf)
     {
         case LH:
             tree->bf = ls->bf = EH;
             RotateRight(tree);
             taller = false;
             break;
         case EH:
             cerr << "Tree already balanced " << endl;
             break;
         case RH:
             rs = ls->left;
             switch (rs->bf)
         {
             case LH:
                 tree->bf = RH;
                 ls->bf = EH;
                 break;
             case EH:
                 tree->bf = ls->bf = EH;
                 break;
             case RH:
                 tree->bf = EH;
                 ls->bf = LH;
                 break;

         }
             rs->bf = EH;
             RotateLeft(tree->left);
             RotateRight(tree);
             taller = false;
     }

 }
#endif /* AvlClass_h */
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TreeType.h"
using namespace std;

TreeType<string>tree;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int option;
    do
    {
        cout << "\t1. Insert into an AVL Tree\n";
        cout << "\t2. Print the contents of the AVL tree\n";
        cout << "\t3. Exit\n";
        cout << "\t\tEnter option : ";
        cin >> option;

        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
                //Insert
                tree.InsertItem("dean");
                tree.InsertItem("joe");
                tree.InsertItem("jason");
                break;
            case 2:
                tree.Print();
                break;
        }

    } while (option < 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you are dereferencing a null pointer.  Time to break out your favorite debugger and step through the code.

Comment: I have confirmed the error.  Hint - it crashes on the last input.  A cout added to InsertItem() reports:  InsertItem: joe, InsertItem: dean, InsertItem: jason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my LeftBalance function, I have changed the following line of code within my LeftBalance function from

```
case RH:
rs = ls->left;
switch (rs->bf)
```

to

```
case RH:
rs = ls->right;
switch (rs->bf)
```